# How could I properly abstract this Blade Template @foreach?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

My *RoleController* sends a array of *roles*:

```
$roles = Role::all();

return view('role.index', compact('roles'));
```

Then I receive it in my *role/index.blade.php* file

```php
@section("body")
  @foreach($roles as $role)
    <td>{{ $role['id'] }}</td>
  @endforeach
@endsection
```

I'd abstract it from the index creating a file *modal-update.blade.php* and then importing it in *index.blade.php* using:

```
 @include('role.modal-update')
```

The abstraction *modal-update.blade.php*

```php
@foreach($roles as $role)
    <td>{{ $role['id'] }}</td>
@endforeach
```

It didn't broke the code, but I think this isn't the proper way to abstract it, I'm doing it because every item from **$roles** will have it's own *Bootstrap Modal*, and when I added into *index.blade.php* It was getting pretty long.

Comment: I think `{ $role['id'] }}` won't work though. Cos $roles is a collection of objects not arrays. I'm not sure I get your question. But if what you're trying to do is to have the $roles variable available to all views, then you should bind it to view in the app service provider

Comment: @djunehor the `{{ $role['id'] }}` is working just fine, my question basically is: When I'm abstracting the `@foreach` from `index.blade` file it still uses the `$roles` variable even when I'm specifically sending it to `index.blade`. Is there a "safer" way to do it?

Comment: what do you mean of abstract?
are you trying to use global variable for all views?

Comment: @Kelvin What I mean by abstracting is Removing a piece of code responsible for the modals from the index file, and then creating a file just for it to be imported to index file.